# How does the frozen model for speech recognition has been created?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After following the steps train.py and freeze.py from "https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md", The inputs of my frozen model(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXMsE.jpg) is quite different from the actual frozen model conv_actions_frozen.pb(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcE6w.jpg). What changes should I make to get the original frozen model for speech recognition?.
PS: My Python version is 3.7.3 and Tensor flow version is 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You are following guide intended for the TensorFlow 1.x while using TensorFlow 2.1. Try using TensorFlow 1.15.

Comment: I downgraded the tensorflow version to 1.15 and tried the same steps.In the end I got the same frozen model as in tensorflow 2.1.I think the tf version doesn't affect the code.